# UWP c# How to get a StorageFolder object of the app's download folder

Tags: c#, uwp

I am creating files and folders using `DownloadsFolder` methods.

I'd like to get the parent folder as a `StorageFolder` instance so I can list and manipulate all the items in the app's downloads folder.

I've tried `GetParentAsync()` from a known `StorageFile`, but the return is null.

```
StorageFile sf = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("testMarker");
StorageFolder dlFolder = await sf.GetParentAsync();
```

Is there any method to access this folder programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

It seems your app doesn't has permission to read the Downloads directory. We can use `GetParentAsync` to get a parent the app has permissions for, but not to get folders the app doesn't have permissions in.

If we add the Music Library, Pictures Library and Videos Library to the Capabilities of the appxmanifest that we can use the `GetParentAsync` method to get the parent folder as a `StorageFolder` in these folder.

> If you create a file or folder in the Downloads folder, we recommend that you add that item to your app's FutureAccessList so that your app can readily access that item in the future.

For more info, please refer the [Locations Windows Store apps can access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/mt188700?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

So if you want to get the other folders and files in DownloadsFolder, you should be able to [Open files and folders with a picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers).

Comment: I'm not trying to get back to the main Downloads folder though.  DowloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync() creates a special folder just for this app's use and that's what I'm trying to get back to.

Comment: The `DowloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync()` will create the file in the a folder that generated by the app. We can not use the GetParentAsync to get that folder. Why are you want to get that folder?

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use a folder picker ONCE to pick the downloads folder (as part of the inital setup of the app).  After that the app has full access to the downloads folder.

This code needs to be called once:

```
        var folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        if (folder != null)
        {
            // Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder
            // (including other sub-folder contents)
            Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.
            FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("DownloadFolderToken", folder);


            var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Download folder: " + folder.Name);


            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Operation cancelled");
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
```

This code can then be used to directly access the downloads folder:

```
        var downloadsFolder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync("DownloadFolderToken");

        IReadOnlyList <StorageFile> fileList = await downloadsFolder.GetFilesAsync();

        StringBuilder outputText = new StringBuilder();

        outputText.AppendLine("Files:");
        foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
        {
            outputText.Append(file.Name + "\n");
            await file.DeleteAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this isn't possible - You can try to get the storage folder by using the Path with `System.IO` directly like so

```
var downloadPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(storageFile.Path);
var downloadsFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(downloadPath);
```

But `GetFolderFromPathAsync` seems to throw an exception, I think windows just won't give you a reference to this folder.